# Find a limit of a function $f$ as $n\to \infty$

Tags: calculus, limits, summation

$f(n)=\dfrac{1^p+2^p+...+n^p}{n^{p+1}}$. I tried to use Squeeze theorem somehow: $$\dfrac{1^p+1^p+...+1^p}{n^{p+1}}\leq f(x) \leq \dfrac{n^p+n^p+...+n^p}{n^{p+1}}$$ As you can predict I get nowhere. I tried to divide to $n^p$ nominator and denominator but unsuccessfully. It is first topic of integrals, so the nominator can be sum of partition of some function. I'd like to receive only hints.

UPD: I have an idea to show by induction that sum in the nominator can be expressed as polynomial degree $p+1$ with coefficient of $x^{p+1}$ equal to $\dfrac{1}{p+1}$. Since book says what is the limit and ask for proving that it's the limit I don't find my idea fair.

Comment: Have you tried Stolz–Cesàro theorem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $f(n)$ is a sequence of Riemann sums of the function $g(x) = x^p$ over the interval $[0,1]$ (you can see this by writing $f(n) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 1}^n \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^p$). So it converges to $\int_0^1 x^p\, dx = \frac{1}{p+1}$.

Comment: Oh, you must be kidding. I didn't expected it.